# Finding expected value of a stopping time dependent on a Poisson process and a variable $n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, poisson-process, expected-value

**Situation:**

> We have that $\{W_t,t \geq 0\}$ is a Brownian motion and $\{N_t,t\geq 0\}$ is a Poisson process such that $N_t$ follows a Poisson
>   distribution with parameter $t$. This process is independent from our
>   Brownian motion. We define the following stopping time: $\tau_n =\inf\{t\geq 0:N_t \geq n\}$.

**Question:** We are given the hint that we must use the fact that $N_t - t$ and $(N_t - t)^{2}-t$ are martingales, and that we must use Doob's optional sampling theorem. The exercise is to find:

> $\mathbb{E}[(\tau_{n} - n)^2]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{n}]$

**My attempt:** I'm getting confused with the way the stopping time is defined, more specifically the subscript $n$ in there. I figured that from the optional sampling theorem follows that:

$\mathbb{E}[N_{t \wedge \tau_{n}}]=\mathbb{E}[t\wedge\tau_{n}]$

And then using the dominated convergence theorem and the monotone convergence theorem to find $\mathbb{E}[\tau_n]$, but this doesn't give correct results. This was pretty much my only idea on solving this exercise so I was going to use the same approach for finding the other expectation except then using the other martingale.

Tips on solving this exercise are much appreciated (rather than a full answer). Thanks in advance!

Comment: "[...] but this doesn't give correct results" It would be helpful if you could state a) the correct results and b) the results of your calculations...

Comment: @saz You're right. My result for a) was that $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{n}]=\mathbb{E}[N_{\tau_{n}}]$, where I don't know what $\mathbb{E}[N_{\tau_{n}}]$ is. I would suspect that we have that $\mathbb{E}[N_{\tau_{n}}]=\tau_{n}$, because $N_{t}$ is a Poisson process. The correct answer for both question a) and b) is that the expectations equal $n$.

Comment: I see. Note that $\tau_n$ is a random mapping, and therefore $\mathbb{E}(N_{\tau_n}) = \tau_n$ cannot hold true (the left-hand side is a "deterministic" constant whereas the right-hand side is a random variable). To prove $\mathbb{E}(N_{\tau_n})=n$ you have to show that $$N_{\tau_n} = n \quad \text{a.s.}$$ to this end, you can use that $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has non-decreasing sample paths with jumps of height 1.

Comment: @saz As a small side question. How am I supposed to think about this sequence $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$? Do we have that $N_1 = 1, N_2=2 \dots$ etc.? Because in that case we'd have that $N_{t}=t$. Or is it also possible that we have $N_1 = 88, N_2 = 89 \dots$ etc. as long as the jumps are of height 1? In the first case we would also have that $\tau_n$ is the first $t$ such that $N_t \geq n$ and thus we would have that $\tau_n = n$ a.s. I think im confusing some things.

Comment: $N_t=t$ does certainly **not** hold true. The sample paths of a Poisson process start at $N_0= 0$, are non-decreasing and have jumps of height $1$. However, the sample paths are not necessarily (strictly) increasing, for instance there exist $\omega$ such that $N_0(\omega)=0$ and $N_1(\omega)=0$. If you don't get along with all of this, then draw a picture of a typical sample path (...or google it...) and then try to find $\tau_n$ for this particular sample paths... this might give you some idea what happens.

Comment: @saz Hm that makes sense, thank you. How is it possible though that there exists an $\omega$ such that $N_0(\omega)=0$ and $N_1(\omega)=0$ for the same $\omega$. Doesn't it have to be the case that we jump atleast $1$ on every step? Or are there certain $\omega$ that will have $N_t(\omega)=0, \forall t$? Because that would go against the jump height of $1$ right?

Comment: No, it doesn't jump on every step. **If** it jumps, then the jump height is $1$. Really, just take a look at some pictures (e.g. this [one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Poissonprozess.png) and read some basic stuff about Poisson process...

Comment: @saz You're right, apologies for not being informed enough. I'll be back once I've got a better understanding of them. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @saz I'm back. I've done some research on Poisson processes and it's more clear now. Looking at your tip that we have to prove that $N_{\tau_n} = n \quad \text{a.s.}$, it makes sense that this must hold. If we look at $N_t$ as the number of "arrivals" (of something arbitrary) at time $t$ then it makes sense that $N_{\tau_{n}}=n$ because at time $\tau_{n}$ we have $n$ arrivals, hence $N_{\tau_{n}}=n$. This is because of the way our $\tau_n$ is defined. I struggle to turn this into an exact proof, however. Is my thinking correct? If so, how do I make this "proof" exact?

Comment: Yeah, sounds okay. Regarding the exact proof: Denote by $\sigma_n$ the time of the $n$-th arrival. By the very definition of the $n$-th arrival we have $N_{\sigma_n}=n$, and thus $\tau_n \leq \sigma_n$ by the very definition of $\tau_n$. On the other hand, we have $N_t < n$ for $t<\sigma_n$ (again by the definition of $\sigma_n$) and thus $\tau_n \geq \sigma_n$. Hence, $\sigma_n = \tau_n$ and combining this with $N_{\sigma_n}=n$ this gives $N_{\tau_n}=n$.

Comment: @saz Thanks alot. However, how come that we don't have by the definition of $\tau_n$ that, since $N_{\sigma_n}=n$ we have that $\tau_n=\sigma_n$? Isn't $\tau_n$ defined in such a way that this has to be an equality? Or does the infimum stop it from being an equality? Also, where does the ''almost surely'' come in, in $N_{\tau_n} = n \quad \text{a.s.}$? Why is it necessary?

Comment: If $\sigma_n$ is **some** stopping time such that $N_{\sigma_n}=n$ a.s. then $\sigma_n = \tau_n$ almost surely... however, that's not exactly obvious from the definitiion of $\tau_n$ (at least not as far as I can see). Re the "a.s.": Many authors allow for exceptional null sets in the very definition of the Poisson process, e.g. they assume only that $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has càdlàg non-decreasing sample paths with probability $1$... that's where the exceptoinal null sets come into play.